# Узнать статус I/O операции С++

Tags: c++

Есть ли возможность контроллировать статус выполнения операций вывода в С++ без `try` - `catch` блоков?

Я выполняю команду `cout<<"Smthng"` и хочу программно узнать, была ли эта операция успешной. То есть мне надо что-то типа Паскалевского `IOResult`, или какой-то вариации `GetLastError()`. Думал, что есть такое поле в `ios`, но там только типы для отлова исключений.

Comment: Так где то - if (cout.fail())

Comment: @0xdb Спасибо, это вариант

Answer (score 2):

По умолчанию как раз операции с потоками исключений не генерируют. Так что можете просто проверять, как закончилась предыдущая операция - либо, например, `if (cout.good())`, либо пользуясь приведением к типу `bool` просто как `if (cout)`. А поскольку операции ввода-вывода *обычно* возвращают ссылку на поток, то даже так:

```
if (cout << "Hello") ...
```

Comment: Я знаю, что не генерируют. Просто можно их облачать в `try`, а не хочется загромождать код. Отсюда и вопрос. Ответ меня устраивает, хотя надеялся на наличие кодов ошибок, а не только `fail`/`good`

Comment: Если не генерируют, то что вы хотите добиться с помощью `try/catch`? Он просто не будет работать...

Comment: Ну да, недоподумал...